# What is the reason for differences for Genesis 3:9 among Bible translations?

Tags: genesis, bible-translation

Why Genesis 3:9 have different wordings in different Bible versions? For example:

" And the LORD God called unto Adam, and said unto him, Where art thou?"
" But the LORD God called to the man and said to him, “Where are you?”

Comment: There are seven differences between those translations! Please explain exactly what difference you want an explanation of. Please also tell us what the two translations are.

Comment: Your questions is not quite clear.

Comment: Because they're independent translations?

Comment: "Adam" = "man" (in Hebrew). [H3br3wHamm3r81](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/38789/why-different-bible-versions-have-different-verses-of-genesis-39/38790#38790) says that translating "Adam" in 3:9 is suboptimal, but the basis of the big difference is that there is only one Hebrew word.

Answer (score 3):

The Hebrew text of Gen. 3:9 according to the Masoretic text states,

> וַיִּקְרָא יְהוָה אֱלֹהִים אֶל הָאָדָם וַיֹּאמֶר לוֹ אַיֶּכָּה

The Hebrew word הָאָדָם (*ha-adam*) is composed of the definite article הָ (*ha*) prefixed to the noun אָדָם (*adam*). While the word אָדָם by itself may be translated as either "(a) man" or "Adam" (Gesenius, p. [13](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewchaldeelex00geseuoft#page/12/mode/2up)), whenever the word is prefixed with the definite article, it probably means "the man" and not "Adam." It would be highly unorthodox for a proper name to be prefixed with the definite article in Hebrew. For example, we see דויד (*David*), never הדויד (*ha-David*). Thus, it would be translated into English as,

> And Yahveh God called to the man and said to him, "Where are you?"